# How to use a function parameter as a type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I have a `check_value` function which expects the parameter `value` and `value_type`, compares `type(value)` with `value_type` and depending on the outcome returns the value or raises an `Exception`. Now I want to use type hints to annotate both parameters and the return type.

```
def check_value(value: "value_type", value_type: type) -> "value_type":
    if type(value) is value_type:
        return value
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Value '{value}' should be of type '{value_type}' instead of type '{type(value)}'.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check_value(2, int)) # works, returns
    print(check_value(2, str)) # works, raises Exception
```

The annotation of the parameter `value_type` works fine, but [forward referencing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) `value_type` as a type hint (since the type of `value`/`the returned value` are of type `value_type`) causes an warning in Pycharm_2018.1.4 (see picture below).

[image]

Is it a bug in Pycharm? Did I do something wrong? Is it not possible to use type hints this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Python's static type checking system can support a function like the one you've shown. That's because the value of `value_type` is not static at all, but determined at runtime. I think, the best you can do is something like this:

```
T = typing.TypeName("T")

def check_value(value: T, value_type: type) -> T:
    ...
```

The fact that the `value_type` argument should be bound to the same type that `T` represents is not something that can be represented with type annotations.

But if you're doing static type checking, this kind of function shouldn't be necessary. If you've properly annotated the places where `value` comes from and the places it will be used, the static type checker should already know if it is of an appropriate type, without needing there to be a function to check it at runtime. It won't really work in your example, since `print` accepts `Any` arguments, but for functions that specifically expect either `int`s or `str`s, you should just pass the value in and let the type checker spot the issue:

```
def source_of_ints() -> int:
    return 2

def function_that_takes_an_int(value: int) -> None:
    print(value) # or whatever

def function_that_takes_a_str(value: str) -> None:
    print(value) # or whatever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value = source_of_ints()           # value's type can be inferred by static type checker
    function_that_takes_an_int(value)  # works and passes type check too
    function_that_takes_a_str(value)   # works at runtime, but type checker will see an error
```

Comment: Function signature could be annotated as follow: `def check_value(value: T, value_type: Type[T]) -> T:`